# Add a space between underline and a nav item on hover

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I would like the underline effect that appears on hover to have a padding/margin of app. 5px from the text, just to have some space between.

Here's the code and link to Codepen:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MbmBjp

Thank you!

```css
* {
  background-color: blue;
}
    
nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 35px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
    
    
/*Underline animation*/
    
li > a {
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
    
li > a:hover {
  color: yellow;
}
    
li > a:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: yellow;
  visibility: hidden;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out 0s;
}
    
li > a:hover:before {
  visibility: visible;
  transform: scaleX(1);
}
```

```html
<nav class="menu" id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">SERVICE</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">WORK</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">BLOG</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Variant #01:**

Increase or decrease `bottom` value in the following selector:

```
li > a:before {
    bottom: -5px;  /* Change in this value will increase or decrease gap */
}
```

```css
* {
  background-color: blue;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 35px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
}


/*Underline animation*/

li > a {
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li > a:hover {
  color: yellow;
}

li > a:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  bottom: -5px;
  background-color: yellow;
  visibility: hidden;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out 0s;
}

li > a:hover:before {
  visibility: visible;
  transform: scaleX(1);
}
```

```html
<nav class="menu" id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">SERVICE</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">WORK</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">BLOG</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

**Variant #02:**

Set following css on `<a>`:

```
li > a {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding-bottom: 5px; /* Change in padding-bottom value will increase or decrease gap */
}
```

```css
* {
  background-color: blue;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 35px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
}


/*Underline animation*/

li > a {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li > a:hover {
  color: yellow;
}

li > a:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: yellow;
  visibility: hidden;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out 0s;
}

li > a:hover:before {
  visibility: visible;
  transform: scaleX(1);
}
```

```html
<nav class="menu" id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">SERVICE</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">WORK</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">BLOG</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PbmBpY

```
li > a:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  bottom: -5px;
  background-color: yellow;
  visibility: hidden;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out 0s;
```

}

add `bottom: -5px;`  to the  `li > a:before`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a codepen that solves it: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zowLZp

Add a `padding-bottom: 4px` to the `li > a` rule, remove the `height: 1px` from the li > a:before`rule, and add a`border-bottom: 1px solid white` to that same rule.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your css : **li > a:hover**

```
li > a:hover {
  color: yellow;
  padding-bottom:5px;
}
```

Check below code snippet.

```css
* {
  background-color: blue;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 35px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
}


/*Underline animation*/

li > a {
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li > a:hover {
  color: yellow;
  padding-bottom:5px;
}

li > a:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: yellow;
  visibility: hidden;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out 0s;
}

li > a:hover:before {
  visibility: visible;
  transform: scaleX(1);
}
```

```html
<nav class="menu" id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">SERVICE</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">WORK</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">BLOG</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change the value of `bottom` in the `li > a:before` selector to `-5px`.
If you do not want to use negative values you can use something like `top: 20px` and remove `bottom: -5px`.

```css
* {
  background-color: blue;
}
    
nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 35px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
    
    
/*Underline animation*/
    
li > a {
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
    
li > a:hover {
  color: yellow;
}
    
li > a:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  bottom: -5px;
  background-color: yellow;
  visibility: hidden;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out 0s;
}
    
li > a:hover:before {
  visibility: visible;
  transform: scaleX(1);
}
```

```html
<nav class="menu" id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">SERVICE</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">WORK</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">BLOG</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

**[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/t60qv8a1/1/)**

```
li > a:hover {
  color: yellow;
  padding:10px 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

add `padding-bottom: 5px` in below your css..

```
 li > a:hover {
    color: yellow;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
  }
```